# Ambiguous Regular Grammar?

Tags: grammar, regular-language, computation-theory, formal-languages

Does such a thing exist?  If so, could you please provide an example?  Thanks.

Comment: Not computer related, but my personal favorite ambiguous grammar: "My father didn't fight in Vietnam so that you could have long hair and act like a hippie." Q: Did my father fight in Vietnam? A: No, I clearly stated that he did not.  In fact (not really, but for the purpose of this exercise) he dodged the draft, joined the hippie movement, and actively protested so that future generations would be free to have long hair and act like a hippie.

Comment: @David lol thats funny, like the glass half full/empty type of thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
A -> a
B -> a
```

can parse the string `a` as both `A` or `B`, and is therefore ambiguous.